# jQuery if string contains a link return link value

Tags: jquery, href

Using regex to check if the string has a link

```
<p>Random text <a href="/landing.html">click here</a></p>
<p>Another paragraph without href</p>
```

and if true return the string and use `str.find("a").attr("href");` to get the href value.

```
var str = $('p').html();
if(new RegExp("([a-zA-Z0-9]+://)?([a-zA-Z0-9_]+:[a-zA-Z0-9_]+@)?([a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})(:[0-9]+)?(/.*)?").test(str)) {
    console.log(str);
    var href = str.find("a").attr("href");
}
```

However, console.log returns error

> Uncaught TypeError: str.find is not a function

Check 
[Link Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0kf7ht3w/22/) in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with above code is you are using `.html()` method because `html` returns the html part not the dom object. You need to use the dom selector object to find the anchor. Update your code to below

```
var str = $('p');
console.log(str)
if(new RegExp("([a-zA-Z0-9]+://)?([a-zA-Z0-9_]+:[a-zA-Z0-9_]+@)?([a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})(:[0-9]+)?(/.*)?").test(str.html())) {
    console.log(str);
    var href = str.find("a").attr("href");
  console.log(href)
}
```

Check the fiddle [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/agamb/0kf7ht3w/23/)

Comment: Thanks a lot, Agam. Works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

Change
`var href = str.find("a").attr("href");`
for
`var href = $('p').find("a").attr("href");`

You are getting this error because you're trying to call the method "find" in a "string", that doesn't have that method.

```js
var str = $('p').html();
if(new RegExp("([a-zA-Z0-9]+://)?([a-zA-Z0-9_]+:[a-zA-Z0-9_]+@)?([a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})(:[0-9]+)?(/.*)?").test(str)) {
 console.log(str);
 var href = $('p').find("a").attr("href");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Random text <a href="/landing.html">click here</a></p>
<p>Another paragraph without href</p>
```